# How to assign Panels to Buttons in C#

Tags: c#

I have 5 panels on a form and i want to set them on buttons so that if a button is clicked a panel set on that button is shown. This should also work on random click.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself or are you just asking for code?

Comment: You may better use a tab control for displaying a panel when clicked on a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button1.Click+=(buttonThatWasClicked, args)=> 
{
    panel1.Visible = true;
    panel2.Visible = false;
    panel3.Visible = false;
    panel4.Visible = false;
    panel5.Visible = false;
};
```

Comment: "a local or parameter name 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because this name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"       getting this error in sender of (sender,args)

Comment: It's just an example. use any name you want that's not already used in that scope.

Comment: can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: not working. should i first hide all panels on form?

Comment: I have no idea what your set-up looks like. You should know what you did, why you did it, and why you think that what you did was going to do what you thought it would.

Comment: just have 5 panels and 5 buttons. wants to assign those buttons on each panel so on a button click only that one panel should be bring to front.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. that worked great